# WordPress 3.0.1 Auto Update Problem

Tags: automatic-updates

My WordPress now is at version 2.7. I want to upgrade it to 3.0.1 using Auto update function. I'm using FTPS connection type.

The upgrade should be straight forward, however, I keep on encountering this error:

> Installation Failed
>   Downloading update from
>   http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.0.1.zip…
>
> Unpacking the update…
>
> Verifying the unpacked files…
>
> Installing the latest version…
>
> Could not copy file.:
>   /wp-admin/css/theme-editor.dev.css
>
> Installation Failed

I've checked the permission for the `/wp-admin/css` folder, and it's set to 777.

What is the problem? I've searched the internet, but it seems that [a lot of people](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-gone-worng-pls-help) [has the same problem](http://warezkeygen.net/could-not-copy-file-public_htmlwp-admincsstheme-editor-dev-css/).

Any ideas?

Comment: 2.7! It's about time. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto update doesn't always work, it almost always works. I'd just upgrade manually and not worry about it. The few times I've had an auto update failure it succeeds the next time a new version comes out (after I'm manually updated during the breakage).

Answer (score 2):

There's a patch (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10913) for WordPress that should go into 3.2 and help fix this upgrade error for most people running into it. It only seems to happen with servers running Pure-FTPd. In the meantime, there's a plugin that should help fix updates for most people: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ftp-upgrade-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the file referenced. In this case: `/wp-admin/css/theme-editor.dev.css`.

Comment: I've checked the permission of *that* file as well, yet I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Owner of the file/s you may have it set 777 but if the ftp service is not in the owner group or the owner this may your problem

You need to telnet into the web server to check/fix this us ls -l to see the settings chown is the how you change it

Comment: Well, I make sure that both the file and the folder where the file is contained has 777 set for the permission.

Answer (score 0):

this has been discussed and explained here: http://nabtron.com/wordpress-update-could-not-copy-file-wp-admincsstheme-editor-dev-css/2714/

Comment: @Nabeel, I've tried the solution, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything for the auto upgrade that was mentioned at wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-gone-worng-pls-help, but to no avail.

Instead I did a manual upgrade more or less following the instructions at codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress. Instead of using FTP, I used my hosting providers CPanel - I then blogged the steps I took so that others might benefit - see http://misterjaytee.com/2010/09/11/errors-updating-wordpress.

Hopefully the next Automatic upgrade will work properly, but if not, I now have the confidence to do the upgrade manually.